# Wordpress show thumbnail within post by posting html

Tags: wordpress

I have some struggles working on a site by adding dynamic html.

This is how it should looks like:

[image]

On the static site it is simple by adding code:

```
  <div id="home-5-year">
    <div id="home-5-year-icon"></div>
    <div id="home-5-year-title">Wij bestaan 5 jaar!</div>
  </div>
```

css

```
#home-5-year {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 180px;
  right: 128px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #03C9A9;
  padding: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: transform 1s, opacity 3s; }
#home-5-year:hover {
  background-color: #03b094; }
@media (max-width: 969px) {

#home-5-year {
    display: none; } }
#home-5-year-icon {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 64px; }
#home-5-year-icon:after {
  content: ""; }
```

For some reason if I add a post containing html elements wordpress isn't showing the icon right way.

[image]

result:

[image]

The wordpress site has exactly the same style sheet and sources.

I also tried adding a thumbnail picture for the thumb but this wasn't working out either. Someone familiar? Maybe other solution how to add dynamic html element with a picture.

p.s already tried to add the image in the post with i, span, div elements but the wordpress editor seems to remove those if I switch between visual - text

[image]

Comment: seems like you need to have the correct font-face

Comment: @Mark sorry for the late response, the font-face is correclty and 3double checked. By some reason Wordpress couldnt get it tho. But if already fixed this issue by hardcoding it...